# Is there a way to import a non-module variable in (browser) ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, browser, scope, es6-modules

This is for browser Javascript. Assuming I have an external Javascript library:

```js
// feature.js
var Feature = { /* ... */ }
```

Normally you refer to the file in your HTML and you get a `Feature` variable in your global scope. Is there a way to import it from my ES6 module so it does not pollute the global scope outside of it? Something like this (isn't working):

```js
// index.js
import "/feature.js"

// Use feature
Feature.foo(); // Feature is not available here
```

---

Also in my specific case, I noticed this library has a UMD statement at the end:

```js
"undefined"!=typeof exports&&(exports.Gmail=Gmail)
```

so I could have a workaround like this but now the global scope has an `exports` variable. Is it a good workaround? Is there a better way to keep it within my module only?

```
        (globalThis as any).exports ??= {};

        // @ts-ignore
        await import("/libs/jquery.min.js");
        // @ts-ignore
        await import("/libs/gmail.min.js");

        const Gmail = (globalThis as any).exports.Gmail;
```

Comment: Try to use import { Feature } from "./feature.js" Feature.foo(); In the feature.js => export const Feature = { ... }.
and then import '/libs/gmail.min.js'; const Gmail = window.Gmail;

Comment: @DavidTeo nope, doesn't work: `The requested module './feature.js' does not provide an export named 'Feature' `. Updated: well in this case I have to edit the provided library, which I prefer not to (I am not the author)

Comment: If then you can use module.export = { Feature }.

Comment: @DavidTeo could you clarify a bit please? Where should that code be at?

Comment: Is there any reason to do this? You could steal the lib from that global var, put it in your scope and unset the global, that's at least one idea that gets to my mind. Otherwise I'd use something like webpack or other preprocessor to include those libraries.

Comment: @vfioox I am working on a Chrome extension that inject code to another website (Gmail in this case). I'd prefer to inject a single script only if possible (in this case I inject my script which would in turn import `jquery` and `gmail.js` libs) and prevent polluting websites that are not mine. You are right I probably can just unset `exports` at the end.

Comment: What does "external library" mean exactly? That you are not hosting it yourself? That you cannot modify it?

Comment: @Bergi I host it (offline) but I don't think it's wise to modify it because in the future I or someone may update that file and do not know it was modified. I can wrap it by referring it in another file but I don't think wrapping it helps somehow.

Comment: All you need to do is append `export { Feature }` or `export { Feature as default }`. Use a build script (can be as simple as a shell command) to do that if you don't trust yourself (or anyone) to update the library without breaking the `export`.

Comment: @Bergi that's a good idea. Currently we don't really have any processor except TypeScript but a MSBuild or a Shell like you said should work. Right now I use the workaround, guess the `exports` variable is not that bad as well.

Comment: An alternative would be to submit a feature request (or do it yourself and open a PR) for the library to distribute an ESM version in addition to the UMD one

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need to add a `export` declaration to that library, there is no way around it.